# Replace a line in a dynamic file using chef

Tags: ruby, proxy, chef-infra, cookbook

During chef client run, it installs ruby as a predefined package of version 2.4.0
I need to update a file before even running any of my recepe
I added below recepe but looks like its not working can anyone help?

`ruby_block 'no_proxy_fix' do
  block do
    fe = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new('/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/uri/generic.rb')
    fe.search_file_replace("IPAddr.new(host)", "IPAddr.new(host).include?(self.host)")
    fe.search_file_replace("end.include?(self.host)", "end")
    fe.write_file
  end
end`

I need to replace below values

**IPAddr.new(host)** with **IPAddr.new(host).include?(self.host)**

**end.include?(self.host)** with **end**

Answer (score 0):

`FileEdit` is an internal API to Chef and you are not allowed to use it in recipe code (read: it is not supported). Use either the `line` or `poise-file` cookbook for this instead.

Comment: Yes I tried search_file_replace_line also, it didnt worked

Comment: `line` is a community cookbook, it works very differently, you'll have to decide which of those two community cookbooks you prefer.